# locate strong html (alone) inside div

Tags: jquery, html

```
<div class='test'>
  <strong> 1</strong>
</div>
```

I tried `$(.test).find('strong')` I think this is not the right way as am not not able locate the element

Am looking to fetch the html for **strong**( value 1 alone and not some text and other sections below .

What is the correct way ?

simple but my bad am not getting it right !!

Comment: @Sushanth-- i just posted this sample to clarify my jquery and not to make syntax out of it.Glad ppl answered it !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you tried the right way (except a copy paste mistake - missing `''`)

```
$('.test').find('strong').html()
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Fpxae/)

Comment: *"Am looking to fetch the html for strong..."* So add a `.html()` to the end of that. :-)

Comment: @ArunPJohny  it pasted yours it worked !! but still wondering what is my mistakee :)

Comment: @user2067567 you were missing the quotes around `.test`

Comment: or `$('.test strong').html();` You don't need `.find()`

Comment: @IsaacSuttell but using .find() is faster http://jsperf.com/jquery-children-vs-find/56

Comment: @Arun Yep, your right. However you still don't have to have it and either way is still quite fast. There are not many applications where you'd notice the difference.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
console.log($('.test strong')[0].outerHTML);
```

Demo: [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/MmN7S/1/)

Or

```
console.log($('.test strong')[0].innerHTML);
```

Demo: [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/MmN7S/2/)

Answer (score 0):

If you have only one `strong` in your html. you can also try for this -

```
$('strong').html()
```

instead using

```
$('.test').find('strong').html()
```

[Try this](http://jsfiddle.net/Fpxae/2/)